# Jasmine spy not getting called, even though the specified method executes properly

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, spy

Im currently implementing Jasmine in my Angular project. But somehow I stumbled across an odd behaviour with spies. I already read some other questions on here having similar problems, but I just have no idea how Im supposed to solve this problem in my specific case.

Im defining my test like so:

```
describe('DialogComponent', () => {
    let component: DialogComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DialogComponent>;

    it('should open dialog and click', () => {
        const button = overlayContainerElement.querySelector('button');
        spyOn(component, 'doSmth').and.callThrough();
        // component.doSmth();          <-- this passes
        button.click();               // <-- this does not pass
        expect(component.doSmth).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

My HTML is basically just a little form with a button that executes a method, like so:

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="doSmth()" class="mat-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
```

The 'doSmth()' implementation is basically just a placeholder in the corresponding typescript file for now, printing something to the console.

```
doSmth() {
    console.log('In doSmth()');
}
```

For some reason I get the 'In doSmth()' message when running my test, but the spy says that the method did not get called. I tried some other stuff, like executing the method not through the 'button.click()', but throught 'component.doSmth()', which works. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried calling `fixture.detectChanges()` after calling the click function ?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Without the complete component/unit test code this is hard to troubleshoot. When I use your code in a simple unit test, it [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jasmine-blitz-7bavhr?file=app%2Fdummy%2Fdummy.component.spec.ts).

Comment: Okay, this is odd. I reduced my code to exactly the code @Fabian Küng used, but it just doesn't work. It really is the same. Im looking into this right now and might update the question. In addition to that, I already wrote a test of another component thats similar to this. It's literally the same, except for the method names etc. I just can't find a difference between those two tests. The only thing that differentiates those two components is that the not working one is an entrycomponent. But I can't believe that thats the reason for it not to work.

Comment: It most likely is the reason though.. I had a similar problem a while back and had to create a dummy test module only for the test, in which I added my component as an entryComponent. Might want to look into that.